# Logs folder is becoming heavy in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have enabled error logging in codeigniter and my logs folder path is `application/logs/`
in this folder files are being created from codeigniter automatically as `log-2015-03-17.php` and `log-2015-03-16.php` etc.

I want that the files which are older than two days should be deleted automatically, so is there any way in codeigniter to do this or I have to create a `cron` for this purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at log rotation: http://ad7six.com/blog/2014/10/25/logrotate-rotate-your-log-files/

Comment: i think so logrotate is a solution for log files where data appends at the end and in my case log files are being created daily mean multiple log files and i want to keep just 2-3 files and others should be deleted from my server. in this case logrotate will also work?

Comment: Log rotation is a concept that simply checks the date of the file and if it passes a threshold it is backed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this isn't supposed to be handled by php/codeigniter, but it is a matter of server management. How, depends on which server you are working on: for instance, on linux, you can use "*logrotate*" (https://serverfault.com/questions/391538/logrotate-daily-and-size), on windows you can get info from here (https://serverfault.com/questions/418410/log-rotation-windows).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use this function to delete logs files

I am deleting here all 10 days older files

```
public function delteteLogFiles_get() {
    $path    = '../api/application/logs/';
    $files = opendir($path);
    while (($file = readdir($files)) !== false) {
        if(in_array($file, array('.', '..'))) continue;
        if (filectime($path.$file) <= time() - 14 * 24 * 60 * 60) {
            // echo '<pre>'; print_r($path.$file. "<br> file created ".filectime($path.$file)); echo '</pre>';
            unlink($path . $file);
        }
    }
    closedir($files); 
}
```

and if you want to clear all the file from log folder please remove this condition

> if (filectime($path.$file) <= time() - 14 * 24 * 60 * 60) {